# Creating a new Google Drive Account for Each of My App's Users

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I'm creating an iOS app that allows users to record video clips and store them in the cloud.

When a new user creates an account on my app, is it possible to create a new Google Drive account for just that user, providing them with 15GB of free storage? (E.g., if my app has 1,000 users, each user has his own Google Drive account behind the scenes. I.e, 1,000 Google Drive accounts total.)

I know typically you'd host these files on S3 or something similar, but does using Google Drive make sense as a cheaper alternative?

Comment: Why not use iCloud? Every iOS user has a free iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way of automatically provisioning a Google Drive account from an API.  According to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk, Google Drive does not offer that capability to developers.  It is only available through specific partners, such as AppDirect (API docs: https://docs.appdirect.com/developer).  You could use their API to register a new Google customer and purchase a Google account, but I think this only makes sense for commercial accounts.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. What if you bypassed the API altogether, and just created a new Google account by autofilling the Google sign up page and submitting an HTTP request?

Comment: What about this: if you want a service, find a vendor who offers that service, and **pay for that service.** If your business model makes that cost-prohibitive, the defect is in your business model. *"Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide."* https://www.google.com/policies/terms/